# A question about "should have done"

Tags: grammar, difference

Is there a difference between

> That Napoleon **should have chafed** at captivity is only natural.
> That Napoleon **chafed** at captivity is only natural.

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence uses **should** which is the proper auxiliary when a clause with **that** states something, not as a fact, but as an idea to be considered. The first sentence says that the idea that Napoleon chafed at captivity is a natural **idea**. It does not state whether he did, or did not, chafe.

The second sentence states the **fact** that Napoleon chafed, and that it was natural for him to do so.

The actual example used seems to come from *An Advanced English Grammar With Exercises* by George Lyman Kittredge and Frank Edgar Farley (Ginn and Company, Boston, 1913). It appears to have been copied in numerous online English courses.

> II. SHOULD AND WOULD IN SUBORDINATE CLAUSES
>
> 307. When a clause with that states something, not as a fact but as an idea to be considered, should is the proper auxiliary in all three
>      persons.
>
> I am not surprised that you should find your lesson rather difficult.
> [That is: “When I consider the matter, I do not find the idea
> surprising.” In “I am not surprised that you find,” etc., the
> subordinate clause makes the statement as a fact.]
>
> It is strange that Tom should neglect his swimming lessons. [Contrast: It is strange that Tom neglects.]
>
> That Napoleon should have chafed at captivity is only
> natural. [Contrast: That Napoleon chafed.]

[An Advanced English Grammar (Kittredge and Farley)](https://bookspublicdomain.com/Grammar/An-Advanced-English-Grammar-by-George-Lyman-Kittredge-and-Frank-Edgar-Farley.html)

Comment: Is it correct to say "That N should chafe at captivity is only natural"?

Comment: Yes, it is natural.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a slight difference.

*That Napoleon chafed at captivity* is (incidentally) asserting that N **did** chafe, as well as its main assertion, that this is only natural.

*That Napoleon should have chafed at captivity* is applying the [epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) meaning of the modal: something  like "we conclude, or guess, that he chafed": it is not asserting that he did. It's close in meaning to saying *That Napoleon probably chafed in captivity*.

Comment: I find I have a completely different interpretation to yours. For me this meaning of *should* is the *happen to* or *it transpires that* meaning. Similar to *It's strange that she should have given him the key*

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference, and it lies in "should have chafed" versus "chafed".

The simple past tense "chafed" assumes as a fact that he did chafe. The sentence goes on to say that it was natural that he did.

"Should have chafed" means that he might have chafed. The sentence goes on to state that if he had chafed, that would have been natural.